# Magic Fields (custom post types) and Custom Taxonomy permalink

Tags: wordpress, post, taxonomy, permalinks

I'm using [Custom Post Template](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-template/) which I linked to [Magic Fields](http://magicfields.org/) to create custom post type named *Company*.
I also created custom taxonomy named *City*.
*City* is hierarchical (like categories), and every Company has one city selected.

For example:
I have a company with post title `Microsoft` and City taxonomy `Redmond` selected.
I want my permalinks to look like this:
`http://www.mysite.com/Redmond/Microsoft`

Just like when you have a post category and wordpress prepends first category selected to your permalink.
Can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found solution to this problem. Here is the code:

```
add_filter('post_link', 'mba_courses_permalink', 10, 3);
add_filter('post_type_link', 'mba_courses_permalink', 10, 3);

function mba_courses_permalink($permalink, $post_id, $leavename) {
    if (strpos($permalink, '%mba_courses%') === FALSE) return $permalink;

    // Get post
    $post = get_post($post_id);
    if (!$post) return $permalink;

    // Get taxonomy terms
    $terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'mba_courses'); 
    if (!is_wp_error($terms) && !empty($terms) && is_object($terms[0])) $taxonomy_slug = $terms[0]->slug;
    else $taxonomy_slug = 'mba_courses';

return str_replace('%mba_courses%', $taxonomy_slug, $permalink);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried the plugin combination you mentioned but "normally", the permalink you want can only be achieved with category listings OR pages. What you want is something like:
http://blogurl.com/categoryname/blogpostname
And this doesn't happen in wordpress.

Your options are:
http://blogurl.com/parentpage/childpage
or
http://blogurl.com/parentcategory/childcategory

Comment: I thought that taxonomies would somehow have similar funcionality as categories (as it derives from the same thing) :/